# how to use the data in parameter and make a format like this @Hours : @Mins

Tags: sql-server-2005

how to use the data in parameter and make a format like this @Hours : @Mins and display and output like this 24:33. because I use A different parameter for the hours and mins. now I want to call it in the UI so I want it to output like this 24:33

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to store @Hours + ':' + @Mins